# How can I read the color of autoshape in python-pptx?

Tags: powerpoint, python-pptx

[image]

Colorful circles are the autoshape type in python-pptx, Now I want to read the color(RGB or whatever) of them

What I got in documentation is use

```
shape.fill.solid() 
shape.fill.fore_color.rgb
```

But It pops

```
AttributeError: no .rgb property on color type '_NoneColor'
```

Any idea to access the color of autoshape?

(BTW, Best to post the color change method cause I read color for change it by HSV adjustment)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the theme/accent colour. Here is an example of how to do this for fonts, the process is rather similar for shapes

[python-pptx: read font color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692768/python-pptx-read-font-color)

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration, problem solved by "prs.slides[0].shapes[0].fill.fore_color.rgb"